# Ignore all files with the same name in git

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a way to have a `git ignore file` to ignore all files with the name test in them?

I have files like this:

```
 - css/test.css 
 - js/subfolder/test.js 
 - lib/main/sub/test.html
```

and so on.

I want `git` to avoid adding or committing any files with the name test.

Comment: This question and many others you may have about gitignores can be answered by reading `man gitignore`, which contains a description of the syntax, and a few small examples.

Comment: no one likes wise guys

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Update `.gitignore` with `test*`

Also, read [this](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html) for more information.

Comment: Why so many votes? Correct seems `**/..` with the two beginning stars. The link does not refer to the 2 stars either. `test*` ignores it only in the base dir.

Comment: @Timo test* ignores recursively. If you prefix with a /, eg /test*, then it would only ignore in the base dir

Comment: I'm getting the same results as Timo - with or without leading slash, a filename followed by a star, e.g. test*, does not get ignored outside of the base dir.

Comment: From `man gitignore`: `A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
           anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 133):

From [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

```
A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same
as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".
```

For your case:

```
**/[Tt]est*
```

it also matches both upper and lower case.

Comment: What does the trailing `*` do?

Comment: @clabe45 Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
1) A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories.
2) A trailing "/**" matches everything inside.
3) A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories.
4) Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.

Comment: @clabe45 you can find more details in link provided in answer

Comment: @clabe45 a * is a special character which means any number (including zero) of any character. So in this case it will match `test.json`, `test.py`, `testosterone`, `testimony.txt.jpg.zip`, or even just `test`. You might try doing `**/[Tt]est.*` with a period, although that will not catch files like `testClient.js`.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the pattern to .gitignore of test.*

Add it and do a git status with some files like you mentioned above.

If it works you're good.